# CMAKE generate a static library that depends on shared libraries

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cmake, cross-compiling

First of all, I am learning and I am very new to CMake, so please, have mercy. I have done some research about this but I have not found anything that actually works for me. I have made many changes to the CMakeLists.txt but I will try to show you summarize what I am trying to do and how I am trying to achieve that.

I have a project folder tree like this:

```
Mainfolder/:
  CMakeLists.txt (CMakeLists1.txt to identify it better)
    lib1:
      source files (.h .c)
      CMakeLists.txt (CMakeLists2.txt)
    lib2:
      source files (.h .c)
      CMakeLists.txt (CMakeLists3.txt)
    executable:
      source files (.h .c)
      CMakeLists.txt (CMakeLists4.txt)
```

Once this has been said, lib1 and lib2 are meant to be built as static libraries and depends on "rt" and "pthread" shared libs for example. Besides, lib2 depends on lib1.
I am crosscompiling, so I load the environment using and script and all the variables seem to be recognized properly by CMake (I have printed them and I verified the crosscompilation by compiling a Hello world example that ran properly on the target).

The CMakeLists1.txt serves as an entry point:

```
project(
  MainApp
  VERSION 0.1
  DESCRIPTION "Main Application CMake compilation project"
  LANGUAGES C)

add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
add_subdirectory(executable)
```

How do I compile lib1 or lib2? Using the following CMakeLists2.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14...3.16)

project(
  lib1
  VERSION 0.1
  DESCRIPTION "lib1 library"
  LANGUAGES C)

find_library(RT_LIBRARY rt)
find_library(PTHREAD_LIBRARY pthread)

list(APPEND SRCS
        source1.c
        source2.c)

find_library(RT_LIBRARY rt)
find_library(PTHREAD_LIBRARY pthread)

add_library(lib1 ${SRCS})

# Include libraries required
target_link_libraries(lib1 ${PTHREAD_LIBRARY} ${RT_LIBRARY})
```

CMakelists3.txt is the same as CMakelists2.txt but including the lib1 dependencies:

```
find_library(LIB1_LIBRARY lib1)
add_library(lib2 ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(lib2 ${PTHREAD_LIBRARY} ${RT_LIBRARY} ${LIB1_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories (lib2 PUBLIC {CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib1)
```

I have to say I also tried to include the lib1 dependency using ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib1/liblib1.a but it did not work either.

These seem to compile well and I see many "U" undefined symbols that I guess will be obtained from the shared library (sorry, I am doubting here and I am not sure if it should be considered as a fail already). In any case, I am not sure if the lib1 is linked to the lib2, and the same occurs with the shared libraries (rt and pthread).

And finally, CMakeLists4.txt which aims to put everything together and generate the executable:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14...3.16)

project(
  Execuable
  VERSION 0.1
  DESCRIPTION "MainApp library"
  LANGUAGES C)

list(APPEND SRCS
        source1.c
        source2.c)

find_library(RT_LIBRARY rt)
find_library(PTHREAD_LIBRARY pthread)
find_library(RT_LIBRARY rt)
find_library(LIB1_LIBRARY lib1)
find_library(LIB2_LIBRARY lib2)

add_executable(Executable ${SRCS})
target_include_directories (Executable PUBLIC {CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib1 {CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib2)
target_link_libraries(Executable ${RT_LIBRARY} ${PTHREAD_LIBRARY} ${LIB1_LIBRARY} ${LIB2_LIBRARY})
```

If I compile each of the libraries separately, they seem to generate properly .a files, but as I try to execute the CMakeLists1.txt, it fails during the linking, showing undefined references in the lib1.a about, for example, shm_open (I found it is related to "rt" shared lib). So, I am not sure how to solve this situation.
Any help will be more than welcome.

Best regards,
Fulgo.

Comment: For link with a library created in the same CMake project, just use name of its **target**, not a path to that library. E.g. `target_link_libraries(lib2 PUBLIC lib1)` or `target_link_libraries(Executable PRIVATE lib2)`. That way CMake preserve dependencies between libraries, even they are not part of the library file. E.g. the file `lib2.a` doesn't contain linkage with `lib1.a` (creation of a static library doesn't involve linking step). But would your executable is linked with `lib2`, CMake will *automatically* links it with `lib1` too.

Comment: But I am using make CMakeLists.txt, do the targets, lib1 and lib2, propagate to the Top CMakeLists.txt?? Something is not working for me right now.

Comment: Targets in CMake have **global visibility**. If you build your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, then any sub-`CMakeLists.txt` may use library targets, created in other sub-`CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: You are very right. Now everything works. Thank you very much. It is a bit complex and the documentation not very accurate, so many doubts had arisen...

Answer (score 0):

Tsyvarev gave me the answer. I had to avoid using find_library for the libraries built in the same CMake project. This allowed me to compile the project properly.